# DAX Measure - Summing up values between start-end dates in the same table

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have an "Assignments" Table like this:

Date    End Date    Allocation
1111    Alex    AA    11/20/2016    12/30/2016    0.5
2222    Eric    BB    10/20/2016    11/30/2016     0.4
3333    John    CC    10/20/2016    12/30/2016   1
2222    Eric    DD    11/20/2016    1/1/2017        0.5

I also have a simple "Date" Table which ***DOES NOT*** have a relationship with the Assignments Table like this:

Date    Month    Month_Text    Year    Month-Year
10/1/2016    10    Oct    2016    Oct-16
10/2/2016    10    Oct    2016    Oct-16
10/3/2016    10    Oct    2016    Oct-16
10/4/2016    10    Oct    2016    Oct-16

Than I have the following DAX measure:

==============================

Sum of Assignments :=
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( Assignments_Tbl, Assignments_Tbl[Allocation] ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Date_Tbl ),
        Date_Tbl[Date] >= MINX ( Assignments_Tbl, Assignments_Tbl[Start Date] )
            && Date_Tbl[Date] <= MAXX ( Assignments_Tbl, Assignments_Tbl[End Date] )
    )
)
    * CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( Date_Tbl[Month] ),
        FILTER (
            VALUES ( Date_Tbl ),
            Date_Tbl[Date] >= MINX ( Assignments_Tbl, Assignments_Tbl[Start Date] )
                && Date_Tbl[Date] <= MAXX ( Assignments_Tbl, Assignments_Tbl[End Date] )
        )
    )

==============================

All seems OK when I have the Start Date and End Date as part of my Pivot Table like below:

[Sum of Assignments in a pivot table with Start/End Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwaPo.png)

HOWEVER, if I remove the Start Date and End Date from the pivot table, the measure is calculating incorrectly and I can't find why.

For instance, as the pic below, the red circles show 0.9 for a person name "Eric" in in Oct-2016, instead of 0.4.

[Sum of Assignments measure calculating incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stiEs.png)

I tried many things, but got stuck on this measure. Any idea?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I know the issue is at the "MINX/MAXX" because they are returning the entire period when a person has "multiple assignments", but don't know how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deeper investigation, here is the proper measure:

```
New Measure =
SUMX (
    Assignments_Tbl,
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Assignments_Tbl[Allocation] ) * DISTINCTCOUNT ( Date_Tbl[Month-Year] ),
        FILTER (
            VALUES ( Date_Tbl ),
            Date_Tbl[Date] >= EARLIER ( Assignments_Tbl[Start Date], 1 )
                && Date_Tbl[Date] <= EARLIER ( Assignments_Tbl[End Date], 1 )
        )
    )
)
```